# Are numbers like 120 and 120.0 equal

Tags: math, numbers, decimal

I had a math question. Are numbers such as 120 and 120.0 equal? I was confused when looking for an answer and have heard various things. Would love to hear an answer!!!

Comment: This question, as asked, isn't really a programming problem, it's more a philosophy of math or philosophy of programming question. As such, it's off-topic here, but if it were stated a bit more precisely it may be appropriate for [programmers.se] or [math.se].

Comment: You should provide some context. your question is vague

Comment: What do you mean by 'equal'?  This may seem totally obvious, but there are several ways to interpret it.

Comment: Would the answer still be the same if it was looked at as 120 and 0/10?

Answer (score 2):

The **numbers** 120 and 120.0 are of course equal.

However, in the popular programming languages (like C/C++/C#/Java/Pascal) 120 and 120.0 represent different numeric constants, the former being an integer constant and the latter being a floating-point constant.

In math, number is determined by its value. So a real number, a complex number, an even number -- any kind of number with value (say) 120 is the same number.

In software, there are variables and values. The value always has a type, so an integer value is something completely different from a double (programmer's term for floating-point number) value. However there are often *conversions* built-in into the programming language, which allow an integer constant 120 be assigned to a double-typed variable. For doing this, the integer value of the constant is implicitly converted by the compiler to a double value (using more or less customary mathematical rules), and this value is assigned to the variable.

Comment: OK. Thank you all very much for your answers. Would love to hear more if you have more!

Comment: @Denali: added some more information on the topic. You could perhaps tell us what information is interesting for you.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of pure math, the numbers 120 and 120.0 are exactly equal.

In the context of science, the number of decimal points present implies the number of significant figures (which is a rough estimate of the precision of the number).

In programming, the exact details depend on the language.  However, in some popular languages (like C/Java/etc.), there is a distinction in datatype:  `120` is an integer constant, while `120.0` is a floating point one.

Comment: (mathematically speaking) if i were to round 120.123 and i were looking at the tenths place, would i be able to have 120.00 and still have it be correct? OR if it was 120.0?

Comment: If you round 120.123 to the nearest integer, you get 120 (which is of course different from 120.123).  Mathematically speaking, 120 = 120.0 = 120.00 -- they are all the same (and all equally different from 120.123).

Answer (score 0):

Mathematicly - yes, they are totaly equal. In programming languages - it's depends on which language do you use, and how you check their equality.

Comment: So in math the numbers would be exactly the same?

Comment: @DenaliCreative: Numbers are defined by more than the characters that represent them. 120.0 could be a real number, or a rational number, or it could represent a value with a 0.1 margin of error. In most contexts you would consider them to be equal, but they may not always represent the same mathematical objects. This question doesn't have a simple yes/no answer. It's similarly ambiguous in programming languages.

Comment: Yes, they are exactly the same. (and 119.999999... is also *exactly* the same number, see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999... ).

Comment: @Jeremy: from the mathematical POV, _real_ number 120.0 strictly equals to the _rational_ number 120/1, and strictly equals to the _whole_ number 120.

Comment: @Vlad: Aye, but interpret it as a measurement with an accuracy of `±0.05`, and it's "equal", but not equivalent..? (I don't know the terminology.)

Comment: @Jeremy: well, when using notation one has to adhere to the common standards. In the part of math outside statistics 120.0 means exactly 120.0, not "a result of measurement". In statistics the notation "120.0" has a different meaning; first of all, it's _not a number at all_. (Disclaimer: I didn't major in statistics, so I may be wrong here.)

Comment: Can some please provide me with a couple websites stating the correct answer mathematically? Thanks Denali Creative

Comment: @DenaliCreative: You may look at my link about 0.999... and learn from it with a fortiori argument.

Comment: Ya i looked there. Thanks for that!